# neo4j disable "discoverability" (php example)

Tags: php, neo4j

I am doing several request using raw curl/php to the REST API, the api returns a bunch of urls...I just want the data! **Is there a way to do disable that behavior?**

Server is returning about 2.8MB for each request.

Ex: $request

```
{"query" : "START user = node(1) MATCH (user)<-[:TEST_PYRAMID_15x15x15_NOT_UNIQUE_II]-(friend)  return distinct friend limit 1","params" : { }}
```

PHP

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json","Accept:  application/json; charset=UTF-8","Content-length: ".strlen($request)));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Response:

```
 {
  "columns" : [ "friend" ],
  "data" : [ [ {
    "paged_traverse" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/366/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
    "outgoing_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/366/relationships/out",
    "data" : {
      "fbfullname" : "NAME",
      "fbid" : "6969696969696969"
    },
    "all_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/366/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
    "traverse" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/366/traverse/{returnType}",
    "self" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/366",
    "all_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/366/relationships/all",
    "property" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/366/properties/{key}",
    "outgoing_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/366/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
    "properties" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/366/properties",
    "incoming_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/366/relationships/in",
    "incoming_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/366/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}",
    "extensions" : {
    },
    "create_relationship" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/366/relationships"
  } ] ]
}
```

I know if I ask for a particular property, neo4j will return only that part, but I do not know beforehand the properties.  "Ex return friend.fbid"

Answer (score 0):

If you return nodes/rels/paths, the REST API will return the full representation. We are thinking about a function in Cypher to return the properties on a node/rel though.